# /storage/emulated/0 not visible in windows explorer

Tags: android, windows, explorer, android-internal-storage

I have an Android 5.1 device and I'm using Windows 7. Let's say I create a folder using windows explorer at location `Computer\HUAWEI M2-A01W\Internal storage\test`. I can access this folder by using the path `/storage/emulated/0/test` in Android. That works well.

Let's now assume that I save an image in Android at the location `/storage/emulated/0/test2/image.png`. I can retrieve this image using `adb pull /storage/emulated/0/test2/ C:\Users\username\Desktop\`. But I don't see the folder `test2` or the image in windows explorer.

How can I make it visible in windows explorer?

Comment: Unplug your device on PC and plug again. This works for me.

Comment: that's known Android bug, which nobody is going to fix unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not inform the media store about the new file. And as Windows and Android communicate using MTP protocol Windows will not see the file.

For an immediate solution: reboot your Android device.

For a better solution: Broadcast your new file to the media scanner.